# what does it mean when some one says " I was calculating your cake penalty"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Someone sent me an email with the following phrase. I was wondering if this is a known phrase.

> I was just calculating your cake penalty.

Comment: Maybe something to do with the game Portal?

Comment: @JohnFX - Can't be.  The cake is a lie.

Comment: Not true: http://bit.ly/m3oJuy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't. Ask your correspondent.

Answer (score 1):

Cake penalties are used by emergency services in the UK. If you violate a work expectation (being late, being unprepared, making a safety mistake etc), you are expected to bring cakes for your coworkers. https://cakeoffencesact.uk/police/index.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

[Googling the phrase](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22cake%20penalty%22%20%2btennis&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22cake%20penalty%22%20-icing%20-wedding%20-carrot%20-mint%20-shootout%20-shots%20-surf%20-marriage%20-shot%20-piece%20-patty%20-coconut%20-takes%20-fairy%20-applesauce%20-chocolate%20-mud%20-cream&hl=en&prmd=ivnsb&ei=vQT-TemzDceUtwfXt7GoCQ&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=96379b3f14f3d8fd&biw=1280&bih=705) and filtering out unrelated occurances brings up enough hits to indicate that the phrase might have some very narrow currency—though I couldn't discern the actual meaning. There are a couple references to penalties involving various numbers of *cakes*. I also found the phrase mentioned in the context of tennis on one site.

Many of the hits I filtered out were similar to @kiamlaluno's find and refer to *patty-cake* or *fairy-cake* penalties in various sports which I took to mean *undeserved* or *silly*.

*[Cake](http://cake.urbanup.com/405742)* can also be used to describe something as easy—a shortening of the idiom *piece of cake*.

Let us know if any of this helps and if you get an answer back from the person who wrote it.